# Is there any software/tool to covert computer generated audio (TTS) into professional voice over?

Tags: voice, voice-manipulation

I need a lot of voice over recorded, but it is costing a lot to hire real voice over artist. Is there any way I can convert "text to speech" audio into real voice over?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No, Ashok, there is not. If you are doing this for a client then you need to pass on the cost of the voice talent.

Comment: Thank you. I tried Google wavenet. It is somewhat closer to what I am expecting.